# Install selected apk: why it doesn't work?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have created this code to display the files in a folder of your phone. Now, my intention is that on click on one of these files (apk files) in the folder is installed the apk selected. This is the code

```
 private List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
 ApplicationInfo ai;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+File.separator+"MyFolder");
        ListDir(root);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){ 
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String appPos = fileList.get(position);

        Uri packageUri = Uri.parse("package:"+getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
        Intent installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, packageUri);

        try {

        startActivity(installIntent);
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            final AlertDialog alertDialog1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(RestoreApp.this).create();
            alertDialog1.setTitle("Error");
            alertDialog1.setMessage("Unable open the selected activity");
            alertDialog1.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    alertDialog1.dismiss();
               }
            });
             alertDialog1.show();
        }
        }


    void ListDir(File f){
     File[] files = f.listFiles();
     fileList.clear();
     for (File file : files){
     fileList.add(file.getName());

     }

     ArrayAdapter<String> directoryList
     = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
       android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fileList);
     setListAdapter(directoryList);
    }

}
```

When i click on a Item Show the dialog which means that goes into ActivityNotFoundException. Why? How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

use setContentView() in your onCreate method after super.onCreate(), that should resolve the issue.

Comment: I haven't a layout for this ListActivity